# Combining regex expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to combine these two separate regular expressions so I can pass them into the oobDescription.replace together and replace all the plain text websites with href tagged sites. I have found a few different answers for how to do it, but I can't seem to get the syntax right and I have no experience with regular expressions.

The expressions work correctly, separate from one another, catching http/https/ftp/www addresses (I know it's not very robust but it's all I need for this).

This is done inside of a javascript function:

```
 var urlLink = /(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\/\\\+&%\$#\=~;\{\}])*/gi;
 var urlLink2 = /(www)\.+(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\/\\\+&%\$#\=~;\{\}])*/gi;

 linkedDescription = oobDescription.replace(urlLink, '<a href="$&">$&</a>') ;


 return Xrm.Page.getAttribute("gdc_testfield").setValue(linkedDescription);
```

Comment: I don't really understand if you just want a gigantic `|`, and make the regex even bigger and less readable than it already is, while still using absolutely no comments, or whether there is some other idea behind it. What's the problem with calling replace twice?

Comment: @ASDFGerte Calling replace twice will end up replacing URLs that are already inside `href`, resulting in doubled hrefs.

Comment: Ah, true, the replace is matched by the other. Then lets look at this a bit more - The two regexes major part is completely identical ([...]`(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\/\\\+&%\$#\=~;\{\}])*/gi`), one will then also wonder why the second one e.g. matches things like "www.........google.com" (many similar odd matches for both regexes) and the question arises why there are not just a few `?` behind the "http|https|ftp" and similar groups and another optional "www" one. The main part is that this entire thing is absolutely unreadable and adding a gigantic `|` will turn it even more so

Comment: Like I said I have no experience with regular expressions, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them using the `|` alternative operator.

```
var urlLinkBoth /(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\/\\\+&%\$#\=~;\{\}])*|(www)\.+(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\/\\\+&%\$#\=~;\{\}])*/gi;
```

This is safe to do in your case because you're only using `$&` in the replacement string. If you were using capture groups like `$1`, `$2` it would be a problem because the group numbers would be different depending on which alternative was matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them with a regex or like this:

```
/((http|https|ftp)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\/\\\+&%\$#\=~;\{\}])*)|((www)\.+(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\/\\\+&%\$#\=~;\{\}])*)/gi
```

One concern you should potentially have is cross site scripting though, if the source of your urlLink can be untrusted data.